# Как развернуть asp.net mvc приложение на сервер, для общего доступа

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis, hosting

Передо мной стоит задача поставить уже готовое asp.net mvc приложение на сервер для всеобщего доступа.

Приложение использует базу данных, которая доступна только из их сети, и сетевую папку, с которой загружает .pdf и которая тоже доступна только из их сети.

Поэтому, и не только поэтому, вариант кинуть приложение на какой-то бесплатный хостинг скорее всего не рассматривается, т.к. само приложение с большой долей вероятности там работать не будет. Разрешить новые ip адресы на базе и папке не могу, т.к. у меня есть только read only права.

В этом деле я новичок, и поэтому хотел спросить, есть ли какой-нибудь разумный способ как поставить приложение на сервер или куда-то, где оно будет работать? :)

Я слышал что-то об IIS, но как я уже говорил, я в этом деле новичок и не знаю что и к чему. Возможно ли поставить приложение на IIS так, чтобы получить нормальную ссылку (типа www.app.company.con), и чтобы на сайт могли зайти с других компьютеров, а не только с того где это было сделано?

Я пробовал развернуть приложение на IIS, но максимально, что мне удалось сделать - это поставить его на localhost и получить ошибку, что IIS не имеет доступа к чтению файлов на сетевой папке.

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку, как дать права для IIS, как поставить приложение на реальный адрес, и будет ли оно вообще работать, так как я описал через IIS.

Comment: сеть локальная?

Comment: да, сеть вроде бы локальная, но надо сделать, чтобы хотя бы в этой сети работало )